# cordova image upload with filetransfer error

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-transfer, imgur

I am trying to upload am image to imgur with cordova.
The following is the code that i am using

```
var fileTransfer = {
  startUpload: function(fileUrl) {

    var uploadServer = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json';
    var apiKey = '<key id>';

    /* global FileUploadOptions */
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.headers = {
      'Authorization': apiKey
    };
    options.params = {};
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileUrl, encodeURI(uploadServer), fileTransfer.uploadSuccess, fileTransfer.uploadFail, options);

  },

  uploadSuccess: function(r) {
    console.log(r);

  },

  uploadFail: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

The error message is :

```
{
  body: "{data :{ error : No image data was sent to the upload api ,request :\ / 3\ / image.json ,method :POST }, success :false, status :400}"
  code: 1
  exception: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json"
  http_status: 400
  source: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.hiapp.hiapp/cache/1461877896871.jpg"
  target: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json"
}
```

but the image is present at the source.

Comment: The server can't upload from a `file://` address, as it's only accessible on your local PC.  Try it with an online image instead.

Comment: I think the reason it is happening is because the file needs to be associated to an "image" parameter. like an ajax post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the filekey that needs to be set as "image".
The working code

```
var ft;

var fileTransfer = {
  startUpload: function(fileUrl) {
    var uploadServer = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/';
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = 'image'; //This is the important point
    options.fileName = fileUrl.substr(fileUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
    options.headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Client-ID <the id>'
    };
    options.params = {};
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileUrl, encodeURI(uploadServer), fileTransfer.uploadSuccess, fileTransfer.uploadFail, options);
  },


  uploadSuccess: function(r) {
    console.log(r);
  },

  uploadFail: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```